# jsoup : get last index after select

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

My problem is that I have multiple `span` tags within a `p` tag.

I want only the HTML code within the innermost `span` tag.

Ex:

```
<span>
  <span>
    <span>
      <span> <strong> lkfghsij</strong> hi how are u?
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Here I want only the `strong` tag and the text after it to be written into a file.

How do I go about this? Regards.

Answer (score 2):

solved...it was pretty simple...just add:

```
select().last().html();
```

Comment: here in stackoverflow, to indicate solved questions, we accept answers, and its ok to accept your own answer. so incase you are sure that there can't be a better solution, you should accept this answer. you can read more about [accepting here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).